# How to use NLog from multiple projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, wpf, logging, dll, nlog

I searched the net for a really simple question. My solution is **one exe (WPF) project and four class libraries**. I need a logging and I like NLog. How can I use it from all of the 5 projects in one solution ?

I don't know, do I need to create (or get somewhere) a wrapper class project referenced from all of the projects and use Nlog from there ? I saw something like this written for log4Net.

Or is there some pattern or best practice for this scenario ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just reference NLOG directly in each of the projects and use it. But you only need to configure it in your main application. The configuration will then be shared automatically.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? What do you mean by 'Main Project' I can I tell it is the 'Main Project'

Comment: The project that is the StartUp Project (i.e. contains the application or program class that launches the application).

Comment: Seems that, in a perfect world, this makes the entire application dependent on NLog. I'm searching for a way that decouples the logging function from the rest of the application.

Comment: @EoRaptor013 In that case, you may need to write a custom wrapper class for NLog and have a contructor to accept the class name. Use that custom wrapper class everywhere and pass the classname. So you can get rid of NLog dependency in individual projects